# How to place non-rectangular clickable "pushpin" elements on an <img>?

Tags: html, image

Basically, I have to create this in HTML/CSS/Javascript:
[image]

As you can see, it's a map of New York. When the user clicks on one of the icons below the map, pins such as those on the lower left part of the map should appear on it at certain locations. The user should then be able to click on them so that another div pops up from them with some text. This is where I'm at a loss. Here's what I thought of so far:

-Creating another 3 images containing either all powerplant pins, all shipyard pins and all steel mill pins and positioning them on top of the map with a z-index. The only problem is, the user will only be able to click the image with the highest z-index. For example, if they enable both shipyards and steel mills, they would only be able to click on the pins last added. This is where I dropped this idea.

-Using divs with absolute positions to replicate the subdivisions of the map. However, divs are rectangular, the subdivisions are not. So this isn't good either.

-Using image maps. I haven't heard of anyone using these since the 1990's. Anyway, I don't see how a map would help me. I need to position them, not hyperlink them.

I'm open to any suggestions/plugins.

Comment: don't forget to accept or comment if the answer is helpful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you might not love this answer, but since nobody else has suggested anything, here's how I'd do it (or maybe actually use an image map with multiple layers, but then your pins need to be on the images):

OPTION 1: do the whole map and pins as SVG and paste the svg code into your html, and attach the javascript click events to it. SVG elements can use the same DOM events as html elements, can be positioned, scaled, and shaped. You can even hide them with CSS rules and classes!

SVG is really quite an elegant solution with solid browser support and if it is possible to get your art assets in that form, that's probably how I'd do it. You can get various tools and tutorials online for svg, so I'll leave it at this, just remember javascript events do work on it!

OPTION 2: do it yourself with HTML. Let me spell this out a bit more as it isn't quite as standard in web, though it is the same idea used in desktop apps.

1. Create four images: the map, and the pins.
2. Create a data array that is a bitmap of the pin, showing transparent and clickable portions. This is a rectangle with 1 where you can click and 0 where you can't, forming the shape. This technique is used in desktop programs a lot for mouse cursors and stuff like that. Easiest way to make it is probably to use an image editor and clear it out to white and black, then export. GIMP can export to an xpm, which you can manually fix up to make into Javascript pretty easily.
3. Create data arrays of the position of each pin. (Ideally, I'd do this as a list of absolutely positioned HTML link elements just because that is a data format that degrades gracefully - if imperfectly - without Javascript, but you do NOT want to listen for events on them.)
4. Put an event listener on the div *containing* all the images and use the coordinates of the click to look up pins in your data array. Use the bitmap to descend if needed - you loop through the possible objects and see if you are in the bounding rectangle. If so, check the bitmap. If it is clickable, you have a hit! If not, move on to the next one.

A linear search is easiest to implement and works pretty well, though if you have thousands of items you might need to optimize this a little, you can search the web for other algorithms/data structures like quadtrees if needed. But if you have that many objects, the map is probably unusable to the user anyway!

So basically, the clicks would all work off coordinates the data array instead of off HTML elements, and the images are just for the user.

I slapped together a demo of the technique using your image, just lazily hacking it up by cut+paste out the pins. If you have the original images, you can do a much better job.

live link (may be temporary)
http://arsdnet.net/demo.html

copy/paste of code for posterity:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Demo of map idea</title>
<script>
        window.onload = function() {
                var map = document.querySelector(".ny-map");
                // on each click on the map, we need to loop through
                // the bounding boxes of the pins and see which one we hit.
                map.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
                        var pins = map.querySelectorAll(".pin");
                        var i;
                        // we are searching BACKWARD so it checks
                        // for clicks on the topmost pin first, then
                        // proceeds down to the bottom ones.
                        for(i = pins.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                                var rect = pins[i].getBoundingClientRect();
                                if (event.clientX >= rect.left
                                 && event.clientX < rect.right
                                 && event.clientY >= rect.top
                                 && event.clientY < rect.bottom)
                                {
                                        // if we're inside the bounding box,
                                        // next we need to check the transparency
                                        // bitmap to see if it is an actual hit

                                        var x = event.clientX - rect.left;
                                        var y = event.clientY - rect.top;

                                        // pinBitmap is defined below
                                        // "." happens to be the char my Gimp export
                                        // gave to the clickable region, so we check for it
                                        if(pinBitmap[y].charAt(x) == ".") {
                                                // we hit this one!
                                                // toggle class "showing"
                                                if(pins[i].className.indexOf(" showing") == -1)
                                                        pins[i].className += " showing";
                                                else
                                                        pins[i].className = pins[i].className.replace(" showing", "");
                                                break; // all done
                                        }
                                        // if we didn't hit on the bitmap, continue
                                        // searching the one below by proceeding with the loop
                                }
                        }
                });
        };
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="ny-map">
        <div class="shipyard pin" style="left: 140px; top: 450px;">
                <p>This is information about shipyard #1.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="shipyard pin" style="left: 150px; top: 450px;">
                <p>This is information about shipyard #2, which overlaps shipyard #1.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="shipyard pin" style="left: 460px; top: 350px;">
                <p>This is information about a shipyard pin in the Syracuse area.</p>
        </div>
</div>

<script>
var pinBitmap = [
"+++++++++++.++.............++++++++++++++",
"+++++++++++..................++++++++++++",
"++++++++++.....................++++++++++",
"+++++++..........................++++++++",
"+++++................................++++",
"++.......................................",
"....+...............................+++++",
".+++.................................++++",
"+++...................................+++",
"+++...................................+++",
"++.....................................++",
"++.....................................++",
"+.......................................+",
"+.......................................+",
".........................................",
".........................................",
".........................................",
".........................................",
".........................................",
".........................................",
".........................................",
".........................................",
".........................................",
".........................................",
".........................................",
".........................................",
"+.......................................+",
"+.......................................+",
"+.......................................+",
"++.....................................++",
"++.....................................++",
"+++...................................+++",
"+++...................................+++",
"+++...................................+++",
"++++.................................++++",
"++++.................................++++",
"+++++...............................+++++",
"+++++...............................+++++",
"++++++.............................++++++",
"++++++.............................++++++",
"+++++++...........................+++++++",
"+++++++...........................+++++++",
"++++++++.........................++++++++",
"+++++++++.......................+++++++++",
"+++++++++.......................+++++++++",
"++++++++++.....................++++++++++",
"++++++++++.....................++++++++++",
"+++++++++++....................++++++++++",
"+++++++++++....................++++++++++",
"++++++++++++...................++++++++++",
"+++++++++++++...............+..++++++++++",
"+++++++++++++...............+..++++++++++",
"++++++++++++++.............++..++++++++++",
"+++++++++++++++...........+++..++++++++++",
"+++++++++++++++...........+++..++++++++++",
"++++++++++++++++.........++++..++++++++++",
"++++++++++++++++.........++++..++++++++++",
"+++++++++++++++++.......+++++..++++++++++",
"++++++++++.................++..++++++++++",
"++++++.........................++++++++++",
"++++..............................+++++++",
"+++................................++++++",
"+++................................++++++",
"++++..............................+++++++",
"++++++..........................+++++++++",
"++++++++++..................+..++++++++++"];
</script>

<style>

.ny-map {
        width: 985px;
        height: 815px;
        background-image: url('demo/qDOGS-fs8.png');
        position: relative;
}

.pin {
        width: 41px;
        height: 66px;
        margin-left: -20px;
        margin-top: -66px;
        position: absolute;
}

.shipyard.pin {
        background-image: url('demo/pin.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.pin:not(.showing) > * {
        display: none;
}

.pin.showing {
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
        padding-left: 48px;
        padding-right: 4px;
        width: auto;
}

</style>

</body>
</html>
```

Here's how I did it. First, the `pinBitmap` portion which handles the strange shape clicks:

Take the pin picture and open it in GIMP. Use the color select tool to select all the transparent parts by clicking on it. Use the bucket fill, selecting "fill whole selection" to make it all black. Hit Select -> Invert to select the rest of the image and bucket fill it all to white.

Now export the file as XPM. Open this in your text editor and copy out lines 7 (well, the first long one with image data, whatever it happens to be in yours) to the end and paste that into the Javascript.

I put array brackets around it to make the `pinBitmap` variable and since Gimp generated strings, I just used strings in the function.

The CSS at the bottom of the file makes our map and pin images. The `showing` class governs the display of more info. You could also of course do something like `.ny-map .powerplant { display: none; }` etc., to toggle the display of things. When searching for an item to click on, make sure they are visible either with `computedStyle` or just with some flag variables and continue if they aren't!

You'll notice that the pins themselves are semi-semantic in HTML, just with inline style to position them. In the CSS, I did some negative margin tricks to make it show the pin point more where I wanted the coordinates to be, but you can just adjust this however - the JS accounts for all this css tweaking, believe it or not! Just get the coordinates relative to the image from gimp or whatever.

I put details about the pin right there in HTML so it is nicely grouped with the content too.

And finally, the magic function, at the top of the file. It is just an ordinary event listener on the map that loops through pins. The `getBoundingClientRect` function is part of the standard DOM and yields the rectangle the item is inside. A simple 4-part check sees if we are in that box.

If so, we want the coordinates relative to the rectangle, achieved via simple subtraction, then check the bitmap if it is actually clickable... that's it! If not, we consider it a miss and continue through the loop. If so, I toggle the `showing` class to do the rest.

This code should work reliably on IE9+ browsers without needing any plugins or library scripts.

Let me know if you have any more questions about my approach/code.

EDIT: lol i called it "shipyard" but cut out the power plant image. Oh well, you know what I meant.